# mule set http header values from postman rest client

Tags: mule

mule code

```
<flow  name="getDetails">
    <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message." doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" path="getDetails"/>
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON" mimeType="text/json"  ignoreBadInput="true"/> 
    <logger message="xml to json output #[message.payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

      <logger message=" custom header username ... #[message.outboundProperties.get('http.headers.username')]" level="INFO" />
      <logger message=" custom header username ... #[message.inboundProperties.get('http.headers.username')]" level="INFO" />
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"  address="http://localhost:8081/callReservation" method="POST" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>
```

Here i give input as employee xml  in the body

**and in header** **i give username=user1  password=pwd1  in postman rest client**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employee>
<name>abc</name>
<address>add1</address>
<phone>1212</phone>
</employee>
```

**I got like error like below**

com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxUnexpectedCharException: Unexpected character '{' (code 123) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1] (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException) (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException). Message payload is of type: String

**using header and xmlto json conversion is mandatory for me.
can anyone help me out**

Comment: why are you using XML to JSON ?? what is the data you need to send to outbound ??

Comment: XML to JSON conversion  is my requirement.

Comment: What payload you want to put for your external outbound service .. is it JSON or XML ?

Comment: org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: custom header username ... null                                                                                                             but i want header name to be displayed  . that xml json conversion i can able to do. .The main thing using header username and password. displayed in log messaged. it shows null.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works fine for me. HTH.

```
<flow name="getDetails" doc:name="getDetails">
    <http:inbound-endpoint doc:description="This endpoint receives an HTTP message."
        doc:name="HTTP" exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost"
        port="1000" path="getDetails" />
    <json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON"
        mimeType="text/json" ignoreBadInput="true" />
    <logger message="xml to json output #[message.payload]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
    <logger
        message=" custom header username ... #[message.inboundProperties.'http.headers'.username]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        address="http://localhost:1001/callReservation" method="POST"
        contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP" />
</flow>
<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="1001" path="callReservation" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <json:json-to-xml-transformer doc:name="JSON to XML"/>
    <logger message="Data received : #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor:  custom header username ... null

Comment: i want custom header name  but it shows null.  I set header using postmanclient. this is my requirement

Comment: If you are using postman and sending property by clicking on headers, you should be able to log the value with the syntax I have given. Some of your posts having issues around accessing data using MEL so I suggest you to go through the following links and that should help.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Tips

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+MEL

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Non-MEL+Expressions+Configuration+Reference

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the value using following :-

```
<logger   message=" custom header username ... #[message.inboundProperties['username']]"
        level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```

You need to pass the XML in the body of postman

**UPDATE**
[image]

I am getting the value as below :-

[image]

Comment: Same for password .. you need to use this MEL expression, only replace password in place of username

Comment: pass the XML in the body of postman .that working fine. But if i set header username again it shows null only. I tried header in bothways form-data , ------x-www-form-urlencoded in rest client . the above code display header value

Comment: Check my updated answer.. put the username there in header section

Comment: add you able get log  message for the header username . for me still it shows null only

Comment: Check my answer I am getting in Log

Answer (score 0):

Use the data mapper after the http:outBound   to convert to json response.